# How to ignore NA in R?

Tags: r

I am doing some analysis and whenever `NA` is found, my loop stops which takes one by one. So I want to say if my value is not `NA` go ahead and further in the loop. if it is `NA` just ignore it and go for the next one. or even return `NA`.
I tried this:

```
  x=c(5,4,6,4,2,1,5,NA)
  if (x != NA){
  y=x+2}


 Error in if (x != NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Be careful about using vectors in `if()` statement. In your case `x` is a vector, and if you just use it inside `if()`, only the first element of `x` will be used. If you want to check each element of `x` for being NA, try something like this: `y=ifelse(!is.na(x),x+2,NA)`

Comment: `y <- as.vector(na.omit(x)) + 2` (if you don't mind having mostly harmless attributes hanging around you can omit the `as.vector()`.

Comment: @scoa that won't work for ternor's example. It will generate a warning.

Comment: Try this example: `x <- c(5,4,6,4,2,1,5,NA); for(i in x) if(!is.na(i)){ print(i+2) }`

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with `x + 2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x!=NA` is neither TRUE nor FALSE, but NA. You can use the function `is.na` to check if something is NA or not:

```
> x=c(5,4,6,4,2,1,5,NA)
> x!=NA
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> x==NA
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> is.na(x)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> y <- x[which(!is.na(x))]+2
> y
[1] 7 6 8 6 4 3 7
>
```